# Outlook closes when clicking send on VBA generated e-mail

Tags: ms-access, outlook, vba, ms-access-2013

I have been working on database for my own organization for last couple of months. I am using Office 2013.  I have taken the code from the internet to email to my clients using outlook. But no matter how much i edit the code, the issue is still there.

**I have set `.Display` property, so that user can see the message before sending.** The issue is it displays me the message but when i click on the send button, it closes the outlook.  However, if I use `.Send` property of mail, there is no issue.

PURPOSE: I am sending the html email, I have saved the html code in my table, so that I can get template on click of button. Which will be available to user for further edit. Alternatives are highly appreciated! :D

```
Private Sub CmdEmail_Click() 

Dim oApp As Object 
Dim oMail As Object 
Dim olAccount As Object 
Dim olAccounts As Object 
Dim olAccountTemp As Object 
Dim vallL As String 
Dim foundAccount As Boolean 
Dim strFrom As String 

On Error Resume Next 
Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
Set olAccount = oApp.Account 
Set olAccountTemp = oApp.Account 

strFrom = CompanyEmail 
foundAccount = False 
Set olAccounts = oApp.Application.Session.Accounts 
For Each olAccountTemp In olAccounts 
 Debug.Print olAccountTemp.SmtpAddress 
 If (olAccountTemp.SmtpAddress = strFrom) Then 
  Set olAccount = olAccountTemp 
  foundAccount = True 
  Exit For 
 End If 
Next 

Set oMail.SendUsingAccount = olAccount 
If foundAccount Then 
 Debug.Print "ACCT FOUND!" 
 With oMail 
  .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML 'Set body format to HTML 
     vallL = DLookup("[Memo]", "HtmlEmailT", "[ID] = 1") & "rs!CliName" 
     vallL = vallL & DLookup("[Memo]", "HtmlEmailT", "[ID] = 2") & "rs!InvoiceId" 
     vallL = vallL & DLookup("[Memo]", "HtmlEmailT", "[ID] = 3") & "rs!BalDue" 
     vallL = vallL & DLookup("[Memo]", "HtmlEmailT", "[ID] = 4") & "rs!InvoiceDate" 
     vallL = vallL & DLookup("[Memo]", "HtmlEmailT", "[ID] = 5") & "rs!InvTotal" 
     vallL = vallL & DLookup("[Memo]", "HtmlEmailT", "[ID] = 6") 
  .HTMLBody = vallL 
  .SendUsingAccount = olAccount 
  .SentOnBehalfOfName = """CompnayName"" <CompanyEmail>" 
  .Display 
  '.Send 
 End With 
Else 
   Debug.Print "No acct found" 
   MsgBox "The chosen email is not signed in!!" & vbCrLf & "Please sign in first" 
End If 

Set oApp = Nothing 
Set oMail = Nothing 
Set olAccounts = Nothing 
Set olAccount = Nothing 
Set olAccountTemp = Nothing 

End Sub
```

*Company email and company name are not fields.

Comment: When you run this code, is Outlook open already, or do you let the code open Outlook?

Comment: I apologize for not mentioning this. It happens only when outlook isn't opened. If it is open, there's no issue.

Comment: Remove  On Error Resume Next.   Do not use it on your entire code. Once the reason for using is past you need an On Error Goto 0. Does not appear to be a reason for using it here.

Comment: Hi, @niton, thanks for your reply. On removing "on error resume next", error pop-up. And It happens, at both situations (outlook is close or open). It's run time error 438: object doesn't support this property or method.  And highlight the following line: "Set olAccount = oApp.Account ".

Comment: Removing On Error Resume Next is not the answer to this specific question. It makes you fix errors rather than ignoring them. Be suspect of any code without a closely following On Error Goto 0 when using On Error Resume Next. Appears the code does what you want by luck. Anything you do in it will be unreliabe.

Comment: Hi @niton, I am sorry I didn't get you here. Please can you guide me, what's wrong with my code, it's just closing outlook while the email is still in the outbox?

Answer (score 1):

Outlook exits as soon as the last of its windows (Explorer or Inspector) is closed.

You can use MailItem.GetInspector and store the returned value in a variable to prevent Outlook from closing.

Comment: Hi @dmitry, thanks for helping, could you please explain a little bit more, how do i use it to overcome my situation. I didn't get how to use mailitem.getinspector. What do i do after storing the value in a variable to prevent Outlook from closing ?

Comment: Just store the value in a variable - Outlook will not close until a reference to one of its inspectors is alive.